# WPF GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding bound to an object => empty string. Why/

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, user-interface

I've got a `GridView` with a column bound to a property of a class which is an object. Other columns bound to strings and ints are shown fine. But this specific column is always empty.

How to fix that (apart from creating DataTemplate's and converters)?

Why doesn't WPF just call `.ToString()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your source property is not of type string you can use `StringFormat` markupExtension to convert it into string format through xaml only.
Refer to this link if you are not aware of StringFormat for reference - 
[String Format in xaml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I had previously happened to me, column name "/" If you use (eg Date / Time) GridView 's column that comes empty. The problem may be not in string format. The problem will be fixed when you change the column name. Please try.